# Weird Error inflating class fragment in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I just started learning ADT, and am stuck in creating Fragment.
What I did follows the tutorial from http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html .

However, when I run it, it gives me an "Error inflating class fragment in Android", and "app was stopped" shows on my mobile phone. **I did try make MainActivity extend FragmentActivty, but it didn't work.** Besides in the tutorial, it mentions if the minSdkVersion is greated or equal than 11, the activity using fragments only needs to extend Activity.

This is the ArticleFragment.java

```
package com.example.sample3;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
    }
}
```

This is MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.sample3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

And this is my main.xml layout for main_activity

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false">


    <fragment
              android:name="com.example.sample3.ArticleFragment"
              android:id="@+id/article_fragment"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>


android:minSdkVersion="13"
android:targetSdkVersion="18"
```

**I really hope you genius guys could take a minute to help me solve the problem. I appreciate it a lot.**

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are missing the **article_view** xml file. This is needed by the Article Fragment...or is it available in your layouts?

Answer (score 0):

The `Fragment` you are extending is from the support library and you are not using `FragmentActivity`, so as of right now your code will not run. With your current configuration, you need to extend `android.app.Fragment`

Answer (score 0):

Change this 'import android.support.v4.app.Fragment' to 'android.app.Fragment' and try.

Answer (score 0):

Try by using latest library

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

Use `FragmentActivity` to work with that instead of `Activity`

```
import import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
```